# AngularJS - config don't support $rootScope

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

i'm using `$translateProvider` for translation in Angular JS like this :

```
app.config(['$translateProvider', function($translateProvider) {
    $translateProvider.translations('en', {
        'RECHERCHE': 'Search',
        'RESULTATS': 'Results'            
    });
    $translateProvider.translations('fr', {
        'RECHERCHE': 'Recherche',
        'RESULTATS': 'Resultats'
    });
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
}]);
```

it work fine.

Now , i want to get my data (traslation words) from data base , so when i get my data from data base in controller and i try to use `$rootScope` to get my data like this (for example the word 'GAME'):

```
app.config(['$translateProvider', function($translateProvider,$rootScope) {
    $translateProvider.translations('en', {
        'RECHERCHE': 'Search',
        'RESULTATS': 'Results',
        'GAME': $rootScope.gameEn
    });
    $translateProvider.translations('fr', {
        'RECHERCHE': 'Recherche',
        'RESULTATS': 'Resultats',
        'GAME': $rootScope.gameFr

    });
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
}]);
```

it doesn't work , can any one help and tell me how to get my data in `config` from data base ?

Answer (score 0):

The only possible arguments for config is provider. You cannot inject $rootScope to config.

Try something like this

```
angular.module(provider.translation').factory('localizationLoader', function ($http, $q, $locale) {

    return function (options) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http({
            method:'GET',
            url:'<Your url>'
        }).success(function (data) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        }).error(function () {
            deferred.reject();
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    }
})

angular.module('provider.translation').config(function ($translateProvider) {
    $translateProvider.useLoader('localizationLoader', {});
})
```